# React.js create a div that can move objects left and right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a simple div with a left and right button on each side that can move the contents in the middle left and right.

The nearest example of this is the following:

[image]

---

Then when you click the right arrow it moves to this screen.

[image]

Is there a React.js plugin that can do this, or any open-source JavaScript code?

We currently show our stations like this:

```
<Grid item lg={2} md={6} xs={12}>
  <Card onClick={handleClick} className={classes.card}>
    <CardMedia
      component='img'
      className={classes.media}
      image={props.icon}
      title={props.title}
    />
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

Comment: From your picture, it looks you just need a simple pagination (not exactly but similar to)

Comment: If you want animation you could possibly try a form of carousel i.e. [https://swiperjs.com/demos/#multiple_slides_per_view](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#multiple_slides_per_view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think what you're looking for [this](https://codepen.io/yatrix/pen/WNGOwrz?editors=0011). The below code (and working sample in the link) will create a "view finder". You can take this and sub in your images and MUI components. I didn't want to deal with a 3rd party lib to illustrate the guts of what the code does.

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

const keanuMovies = [
  "Bill & Ted",
  "Bill & Ted 2",
  "Bill & Ted 3",
  "Dracula",
  "John Wick",
  "Matrix",
  "Matrix 2",
  "Matrix 3",
  "Point Break",
  "Speed"
];

// max number of items to show
const increment = 3;

const App = () => <MovieBrowser />;

const MovieBrowser = () => {
  const [visibleMovies, setVisibleMovies] = React.useState(
    keanuMovies.slice(0, increment)
  );
  const [leftEdge, setLeftEdge] = React.useState(0)
  // as long as we've gone right, we can go back left
  const canGoLeft = leftEdge > 0;
  // basically a "peak ahead" to see if the 
  // next right move will go beyond the array limit
  const canGoRight = leftEdge + increment <= keanuMovies.length - 1;

  const handleGoLeftClick = (goLeft = false) => {
    // if going left will fall blow the 0 index, reset to 0
    // else, decrement 
    const updatedLeftEdge = leftEdge - increment < 0 ? 0 : leftEdge - increment;

    setVisibleMovies(
      keanuMovies.slice(updatedLeftEdge, updatedLeftEdge + increment)
    );
    setLeftEdge(updatedLeftEdge);
  };
  
  const handleGoRightClick = (goLeft = false) => {
    // if going right will go past the array len, select 
    // the next index after the previous move right
    let updatedLeftEdge =
      leftEdge + increment > keanuMovies.length - 1
        ? leftEdge + increment - (keanuMovies.length - 1 + increment)
        : leftEdge + increment;

    setVisibleMovies(
      keanuMovies.slice(updatedLeftEdge, updatedLeftEdge + increment)
    );
    setLeftEdge(updatedLeftEdge);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Keanu Movies</h1>
      <ul className="movies">
        {visibleMovies.map((movie) => (
          <li>{movie}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="actions">
        <button onClick={handleGoLeftClick} disabled={!canGoLeft}>
          Left
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleGoRightClick} disabled={!canGoRight}>
          Right
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: thanks I will use this as a guide (since I need to get the data from JSON) - But you have helped me a lot.

Comment: @RussellHarrower it wasn't me, it was Santa. ;)